Changing AudioKit's AudioEngine output to a different node chain
Using AudioKit's AudioEngine wrapper to AVAudioEngine, I'm trying to swap dynamically the output nodes chain but this leads to warnings and errors.
In the example i just have a first chain to record to a file using AK's NodeRecorder and then change the output with a AK's AudioPlayer one.
Issues:

When starting the AudioPlayer console produces a huge amount of identical errors, which seem to have no effect (see // 1. ISSUE: in code example):


ioData.mNumberBuffers=2, ASBD::NumberChannelStreams(output.GetStreamFormat())=1;
kAudio_ParamError from AU (0x11be06700): auou/rioc/appl, render err: -50


More importantly: when then swapping again to the AudioRecorder this produces just an empty file (see // 2. ISSUE: in code example)

I also tried to:

Wait a delay or an AVAudioEngine notification to make sure the engine has restarted correctly, but no improvement.
Detaching manually the nodes breaks the engine.node assignment.
Looking for similar examples in the Cookbook or AudioSynthPro but i could not find.

Question:
Is this an AudioKit 5 issue, an AVAudioEngine one, or am I doing something wrong? What is the supposed way to reset, rebuild and restart the engine with a new audio chain?
--
Here is the minimum code to reproduce the issue (to executing create a new ios17 project and just remember to add NSMicrophoneUsageDescription to Info.plist).
import SwiftUI
import AudioKit
import AVFAudio
import AudioKitEX

enum ConductorState {
    case idle
    case recording
    case playing
}

@Observable
class Conductor {
    
    @ObservationIgnored private let engine = AudioEngine()
    @ObservationIgnored private var recorder: NodeRecorder
    @ObservationIgnored private var mic: AudioEngine.InputNode?
    @ObservationIgnored private var player = AudioPlayer()
    
    var state: ConductorState = .idle
    
    init() {
        Settings.bufferLength = .short
        try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            .setPreferredIOBufferDuration(Settings.bufferLength.duration)
        try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            .setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            .setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: [.allowBluetoothA2DP])
        try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            .overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)
        
        let inputAudio = engine.input!
        mic = inputAudio
        recorder = try! NodeRecorder(node: inputAudio)
    }
    
    
    func record() {
        state = .recording
        
        let silencer = Fader(mic!, gain: 0)
        let mixer = Mixer(silencer)
        engine.output = Mixer(mixer)
        
        try! engine.start()
        try! recorder.record()
        
        // 2. RUNTIME ISSUE HERE:
        // when returning to recording chain after playing an audio, the recorder does not work with no error.
    }
    
    func play() {
        
        state = .playing
        
        engine.stop()
        recorder.stop()
        
        player = AudioPlayer()
        try! player.load(file: recorder.audioFile!, buffered: true)
        engine.output = player
        
        try! engine.start()
        player.start()
        
        // 1. ISSUE: triggers endless amount of identical warnings
    }
    
    func stop() {
        state = .idle
        
        try! recorder.reset()
        recorder.createNewFile()
        player.stop()
        engine.stop()
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var conductor = Conductor()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch conductor.state {
            case .idle: Button("RECORD") { conductor.record() }
            case .recording:  Button("END RECORDING and PLAY") { conductor.play() }
            case .playing: Button("STOP and RESET") { conductor.stop() }
            }
        }
    }
}


dealing with same issue. Please let me know if you have found any solution
